# Responsive site, issue on 1920px

Tags: html, css

I am doing a full responsive web site, when I am on the screen for 1280px everything is ok, but once I go to 1920px screen everything goes down.

But I do not want to set up a media query for 1920px and fix everything again, I just want that the page stays the same on 1280px and 1920px

I have this on my css (stylus)

```
body
 font-family 'Source Sans Pro'
 width 100%
 padding 0 !important
 margin 0 auto !important
 font-weight lighter
```

And in the html I have the `<body>` element and inside I have a `<main>` element.

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `max-width:1280px;` for main element

Comment: This is the best answer right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply Nick's solution like this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <main>
     <!-- your content here -->
   </main>
 </div>
```

and use media queries to set wrapper div's width like this

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1281px) {
  .wrapper {
      width: 1280px;
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
 }
```

so that wrapper div's width will stay as 1280px even if browser window width is larger than 1280px.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper{
    width:1280px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Encapsulate everything in a div that has a static width.

Comment: But the .wrapper goes inside < main > ?